# automated movie clip recording

Tags: capture, movie, avi, recorder

I need to capture video clips during automated tests wich runs over 12 hours.
My problem is that the movies get too big and i only
want small movie clips if an error occurs.
So my idea was to write  c# tool -  which buffers only some e.g. 3 minutes of a movie
and throws away the captured frames before the 3 minutes to find out what the reason of the error is.
If an error occures i want to save the 3 minute before the error occurs. 
It would be nice if this happens in a compressed way.  The recoding session continues and if the next error occures i want to save the next 3 minute clip and so on.
That means i have to capture a stream and make sure that only the last x minutes will be captured
to find out where the error comes from.
What also is important that dual monitors is supported when a vidoe is captured.
It should be possible to set the framerate.
The Trigger will be done via C# code.

What is the best way to do it?
How can I achieve this with c#?

Bernhard

Answer (score 0):

I use [Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 with Service Pack 2 (SP2)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27870) for recording my automated tests. Insert at the begin and end of every major function of your test start and stop commands. Delete the file in the next major function. This way only the last video is stored on harddrive and you can examine it after your script terminated with an error.

Comment: The problem is that the videos are too long if i trigger it via a start and end tag beetween the teststeps. I would like to have the approach when an failure occures to get the last e.g. 2 minutes before. So when a test runs 1 hour and 3 failures are there, i want to have 3 clips with 2 minutes. So in short I want a failure driven recording, not a test region driven recording. How can i do this wiht MEE 4?